# Bulk load data conversion error, date type field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date-format

I have this uni assignment where I am given the script for the database as well as the one for the bulk insert and a dataset of about 1.300.000 records. With the database set up, i ran the bulk insert script and I am getting a bulk load data conversion error.

I asked all my friends if they had a similar experience but none of them had the same issue. I tried to look into that, it would seem that what causes this error to happen is the Date field in the MainTable, so i tried to find how to set the default date to DD/MM/YYYY and to use the / instead of -, all I found was some SELECT that formatted the `getdate()` function and the `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` command but that didn't fix my errors. I deleted the database and repeated the process at least 3 times now and I'm getting the same error every time.

```
CREATE TABLE MainTable
(
    bookCode int NULL,
    bookDt date NULL,
    payCode int NULL,
    payMethod char(2) NULL,
    custCode int NULL,
    custName varchar(30) NULL,
    custSurname varchar (30) NULL,
    custPhone varchar (20) NULL,
    staffNo int NULL,
    staffName varchar (30) NULL,
    staffSurname varchar (30) NULL,
    totalCost numeric(19, 2) NULL,
    campCode char(3) NULL,
    campName varchar (50) NULL,
    numOfEmp int NULL,
    empNo int NULL,
    catCode char (1) NULL,
    areaM2 int NULL,
    unitCost numeric(4,2) NULL,
    startDt date NULL,
    endDt date NULL,
    noPers int NULL,
    costPerRental numeric(19, 2) NULL
); 

SET DATEFORMAT dmy

BULK INSERT mainTable
FROM 'C:\DATA\GeneratedData.txt'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR= ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

And a couple of records from the dataset:

```
2615981,14/08/2018,1,CC,990,Christie,BUCKNER,(+30)000-556-7301,5020,Zaria,RACE,45,ROS,Rosibos,200,151,C,30,15,15/08/2018,17/08/2018,1,45
2616347,17/08/2018,3,CA,403,Ashli,MAXWELL,(+30)000-114-8689,5010,Yovonnda,CAZARES,45,ROS,Rosibos,200,151,C,30,15,18/08/2018,20/08/2018,1,45
```

The error I am getting is this:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 2 (bookDt).

I am getting the same error what appears to be every single row in the text file.

Comment: I'm often find it easier to load a CSV as textual data, for all columns, into a staging table and then transform the data from the staging table to the production table. You tend to have more control then (such as using `CONVERT` with a style code).

Comment: the dataset i am using is not mine, as i said it was given to us. And its 1.300.000 records so changing anything in it would be a nightmare

Comment: I didn't say anything about changing the file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Set DateFormat dmy", try the following:

```
Set Language N'british'
```

Comment: same error once again... i even tried with both set language and set dateformat and still nothing...

Comment: I'm using SQL 2014.  My original language was 'us_english' and I was getting the same error as you.  After changing the language to 'british', I was successful.  Are you testing with your test records or your live data?  Maybe you have an invalid date in the load data?  If a collation or language change is not doing the trick, you could go the route of a staging table as Lamu suggested.

Comment: as i said in my original post, the dataset is given to us by the professor for an assignment, also i asked many people that have the same course as me and none of them had to mess with any settings or the dataset, it all worked perfectly for them

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, it's often easier to insert the data into a string type column in a staging table, and then convert the values afterwards. I've only done this with the Date columns here, but you can do it to the whole lot if you wish:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA stg;
GO
CREATE TABLE stg.MainTable (bookCode int NULL,
                            bookDt varchar(10) NULL,
                            payCode int NULL,
                            payMethod char(2) NULL,
                            custCode int NULL,
                            custName varchar(30) NULL,
                            custSurname varchar(30) NULL,
                            custPhone varchar(20) NULL,
                            staffNo int NULL,
                            staffName varchar(30) NULL,
                            staffSurname varchar(30) NULL,
                            totalCost numeric(19, 2) NULL,
                            campCode char(3) NULL,
                            campName varchar(50) NULL,
                            numOfEmp int NULL,
                            empNo int NULL,
                            catCode char(1) NULL,
                            areaM2 int NULL,
                            unitCost numeric(4, 2) NULL,
                            startDt varchar(10) NULL,
                            endDt varchar(10) NULL,
                            noPers int NULL,
                            costPerRental numeric(19, 2) NULL);
GO

BULK INSERT stg.MainTable
FROM 'C:\DATA\GeneratedData.txt'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');

GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.MainTable (bookCode int NULL,
                            bookDt date NULL,
                            payCode int NULL,
                            payMethod char(2) NULL,
                            custCode int NULL,
                            custName varchar(30) NULL,
                            custSurname varchar(30) NULL,
                            custPhone varchar(20) NULL,
                            staffNo int NULL,
                            staffName varchar(30) NULL,
                            staffSurname varchar(30) NULL,
                            totalCost numeric(19, 2) NULL,
                            campCode char(3) NULL,
                            campName varchar(50) NULL,
                            numOfEmp int NULL,
                            empNo int NULL,
                            catCode char(1) NULL,
                            areaM2 int NULL,
                            unitCost numeric(4, 2) NULL,
                            startDt date NULL,
                            endDt date NULL,
                            noPers int NULL,
                            costPerRental numeric(19, 2) NULL);

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.MainTable
SELECT bookCode,
       CONVERT(date, bookDt, 103),
       payCode,
       payMethod,
       custCode,
       custName,
       custSurname,
       custPhone,
       staffNo,
       staffName,
       staffSurname,
       totalCost,
       campCode,
       campName,
       numOfEmp,
       empNo,
       catCode,
       areaM2,
       unitCost,
       CONVERT(date, startDt, 103),
       CONVERT(date, endDt, 103),
       noPers,
       costPerRental
FROM stg.MainTable;

TRUNCATE stg.MainTable;
```

Comment: That infers that you have data that can't be converted @Sakis.

Comment: What does the following query return @Sakis ? `SELECT bookDt FROM stg.MainTable WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,bookDt,103) IS NULL AND bookDt IS NOT NULL;`? If no results, repeat the process for `startDt` and `endDT`.

Comment: *(Obviously the above should be run after completing the `BULK INSERT` into the staging table, but before the `INSERT` into the table in the `dbo` schema.)*